# Animação CSS de entrada e saída de elemento ao fazer scroll na página

Tags: jquery, css3

Estou fazendo um div aparecer com animação de entrada quando o scroll atinge um ponto da página, o problema é que não consigo fazer a animação de saída quando o scroll retorna.

O `<div class="box"></div>` tem o seguinte CSS:

```css
.box {
    right: -384px;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: right 500ms cubic-bezier(0.265, 0.365, 0.26, 0.865);
    -moz-transition: right 500ms cubic-bezier(0.265, 0.365, 0.26, 0.865);
    -o-transition: right 500ms cubic-bezier(0.265, 0.365, 0.26, 0.865);
    transition: right 500ms cubic-bezier(0.265, 0.365, 0.26, 0.865);
}
```

E quando o scroll atinge determinado ponto, acrescento a classe `display-block` que executa a animação:

```css
.display-block {
    right: 0px;
    visibility: visible;   
}
```

Este é o jQuery:

```javascript
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    var available = $(document).height();
    var percentage_of_page = 0.5;
    var half_screen = available * percentage_of_page;
    if ( height > half_screen ) {
        $('.box').addClass('display-block');
    } else {
        $('.box').removeClass('display-block');
    }
});
```

Tentei criar uma classe extra para esconder o elemento com uma [animação por keyframes](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/), mas não deu muito certo. Sei que é possível usar uma biblioteca como [Waypoints](https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints) para fazer isso facilmente, mas como fazer com CSS e jQuery puro?

Fiz um [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brasofilo/g29pnbeq/) bem básico, pois talvez o Scroll nem seja importante. E também um [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brasofilo/n9wLan73/) mais completo onde se pode ver o efeito.

Comment: Você faz o movimento pelo CSS, não é? E se você fizesse um *move-left* e *move-right* para entrada e saida?

Comment: Sim, o movimento é puro CSS, o jQ só adiciona/remove a classe. Acho que minha pergunta real é como fazer um swap de classes que anime as duas.

Comment: Fiz um exemplo *bem* simples no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uecocggy/). Não tenho tempo agora para incrementar o codigo, mas separei o evento entrada e saida. ficou manual `right: -343px;`, mas pode mudar pelo js depois. Espero que ajude

Comment: Ahn, claro, tem que separar a animação em duas classes extras e tirar fora do box inicial. Só, resolve total! Resposta, please :) Nem precisa complicar muito, acho que é uma coisa básica [tipo isto](http://jsfiddle.net/brasofilo/xeLsy01p/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu caso, aplicar a transição na div box, limita o efeito de entrada e saida. Para fazer a movimentação seria preciso aplicar *removeClass* mas perderia a formatação. Outro problema é que ao recolher a div, você esta usando *$('.box').removeClass('display-block')*, e tira propriedade *visible* tornando oculta sem poder aplicar o efeito.

Uma solução é separar a formatação do elemento e manter o efeito de entrada e saida separados para cada evento. Exemplo online com código completo disponível no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bysxb6pp/).

---

Mantendo a formatação do elemento *box*

```
.box {
    position: fixed;
    width: 293px;
    bottom: 48px;
    right: -384px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    padding: 16px 25px 0px 25px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Criando efeito de *saida* movimentando a div para a lateral.

```
.motionL{
    background:#669900;
    transition: right 500ms cubic-bezier(0.265, 0.365, 0.26, 0.865);
}
```

Criando efeito de *entrada* com posição *right:0px*

```
.motionR{
    background:#FF00FF;
    transition: right 500ms cubic-bezier(0.265, 0.365, 0.26, 0.865);
    right: 0px;
}
```

**jQuery**: A var *status* marca a condição da div( aberta ou fechada ), assim aplica a classe para recolher o elemento *apenas* se ela estiver visível.

```
var status = 'close'

$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    write_status();

    if ( $(window).scrollTop() > half_screen )
    {
        $('.box').removeClass('motionL');
        $('.box').addClass('motionR');
        status = 'open';
    }
    else
    {
        if( status === 'open' )
        {
            $('.box').removeClass('motionR');
            $('.box').addClass('motionL');
            status = 'close';
        }
    }
});
```

**Html**

```
<div class="box">
    <span class="box-title text">MORE STORIES</span>
    <div>
        <a href="#"><img width="326" height="150" src="http://dummyimage.com/326x150/23a343/edfcf7&text=Detect+scroll" /></a>
        <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></h3>
        <p>Neque porro [...]</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O trabalho final está neste [**SOFiddle**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270960/1287812). É o segundo, *Scroll listener. CSS3 animation.* E uma cópia no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brasofilo/gzzk5tq0/) que é mais fácil de ver tudo junto e fazer fork.