# Animações de entrada de textos e divs ao fazer scroll na página

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3, bootstrap-3

Tenho visto que está ficando cada vez mais comum essa prática, onde os elementos da página vão "aparecendo" (***fade-in, slide-in, entre outros***) automaticamente quando, ao dar **scroll**, você entrar em uma nova section/div.
Dei uma **pesquisada**, mas não encontrei o necessário para realmente aprender como funciona e como colocar em prática.

Busquei rapidamente um site que vi tal recurso. É claro que não foi nem um pouco difícil encontrar. Bastou eu colocar "Bootstrap themes examples" no google que a maioria já apresentavam tais animações.

### Confira um exemplo em particular que gostei muito: ["Material Style Theme (Bootstrap)](https://agmstudio.io/themes/material-style/1.2.1/)

Minhas perguntas são:

- Em que é feito?
- Como é feito?
- Onde encontro (em qual biblioteca?) exemplos para estudar e aprender mais?
- O carregamento da página fica prejudicado devido a esse recurso?

Exemplo de uma seção de meu site que gostaria dos efeitos:

```
<div class="site-wrapper">
<div class="site-wrapper-inner" id="portofolio">

    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading" style="color:white">Portfolio</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">

                <img style="width:360px;Height:200px" src="Imagem-removida-por-questões-profissionais" class="img-responsive" alt="">

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4>Título</h4>
                    </div>


                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p class="text-muted">Descrição</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Nesse caso, gostaria que a seguinte div fosse animada:

> class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item

Fale ressaltar que procurei aqui, mas não encontrei o necessário:

- [Não é o que estou buscando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32161/anima%C3%A7%C3%A3o-css-de-entrada-e-sa%C3%ADda-de-elemento-ao-fazer-scroll-na-p%C3%A1gina)
- [Esse é parecido, mas quero que, uma vez a animação feita, o elemento continue na página com ela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16463/disparar-anima%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-scroll?rq=1)

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: [Sitepoint - Scroll with Animations](https://www.sitepoint.com/scroll-based-animations-jquery-css3/)

Comment: Estou dando uma olhada. Parece um bom conteúdo

Comment: Olá, as animações podem ser feitas em CSS e as triggers no evento de rolagem disparadas usando Javascript. Existem bibliotecas prontas especificamente para isso: Para as animações:
https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ Para as triggers das animações:
http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/