# Como ativar determinado CSS a partir de certa rolagem?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Bom dia

Gostaria de saber como ativar determinado CSS a partir de certa rolagem.
Por exemplo, em alguns portfólios, na parte de habilidades, a maioria põe um circulo que ao descer a pagina completa a volta, determinando a porcentagem de conhecimento.

Isso se faz com jquery certo?

Answer (score 0):

Com CSS e jQuery dá pra fazer esse efeito.
Essa questão foi resolvida no seguinte link:

[Animação CSS de entrada e saída de elemento ao fazer scroll na página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32161/anima%C3%A7%C3%A3o-css-de-entrada-e-sa%C3%ADda-de-elemento-ao-fazer-scroll-na-p%C3%A1gina)

Lá foi discutido também como realizar a entrada e a saída desses efeitos usando o  CSS e o jQuery.

Abraço.